# Why do you have to pass the event object as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I'm learning how to manipulate events in JavaScript and I'm wondering "why do you have to pass the event object as a parameter (argument) into a function when using event handling?"

Here's an example of what I am talking about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = (function (event) {
        alert("The event is: " + "on" + event.type);
    });
</script>
```

I wrote the code above and I pretty much understand what it does. I just don't understand the whole (event) passing. I thought of this as a way of assigning an anonymous function to the `button_1.onclick` event handler. Does the event handler try to pass in an event before it gets assigned or?... I'm having a difficult time understanding this. If someone could please clarify this for me I would be grateful.

*[I tried searching it on Google but found very complex explanations and examples. Only a simple-to-intermediate explanation would help.]* =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The Ever-Present Event, Whether You Like it or Not

The event is always present, even when you don't provide a name:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(){
  alert( arguments[0].type );
});
```

That is the same as saying this:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(event){
  alert( event.type );
});
```

*The event object is already being passed to your callback* (whether your provide a name for it or not), you can choose to not use it if you like. For instance, if we looked to a jQuery onClick method:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(){
  /* Do stuff */
});
```

#### Making Use of It

You'll note that I have no event object referenced in my callback. I'm not required to. However, if I want to use it, for whatever purpose, I should give it a name:

```
$(".foo").on("click", function(myEvent){
  myEvent.preventDefault();
  myEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now that I have granted myself access to the event details, I can prevent the default behavior that would result from the event, and I can also stop the event from bubbling up the DOM to other elements.

#### Practical Example

Suppose we wanted to listen for click events on an element:

```
$("#bigSquare").on("click", function(event){
  /* Do something */
});
```

Click events happen on an element when you click the element itself, or any of its children. Now suppose this element had two children:

```
<div id="bigSquare">
  <div id="redSquare"></div>
  <div id="blueSquare"></div>
</div>
```

Clicking any of these, the big square, the red square, or the blue square will cause the "click" event on the big square - after it causes the click event on whichever element you clicked first (events bubble up the DOM).

We could determine which element was the target in any click event via the event itself:

```
$("#bigSquare").on("click", function(event){
  alert( event.target.id );
});
```

Note here how we're accessing the ID of the target that raised the event. If you click on the red square, when that event bubbles up to the big square, we will see alerted "redSquare". The same goes for the blue square. If you click that, the event will bubble up to the big square and we will see alerted "blueSquare".

You can test this online via the following demo: http://jsbin.com/ejekim/edit#javascript,live

Try clicking the orange, red, or blue square to see what is alerted.

Comment: So it would be something like:if (event.xcord === 500 && event.ycord === 500) { alert("Your in the center of the room."); // more code } else { alert("Your not in the center of the room."); // more code }

Comment: Not those names exactly, but yes, along those lines.

Comment: @W3Geek I've added an important bit of information to the start of my answer that should clear things up for you.

Comment: I really like how you put that. I still don't understand what capturing, bubbling, and event callbacks mean yet. I think that's why things are so confusing to me. A callback is basically the function code correct?

Comment: @W3Geek Capturing and Bubbling are two ways in which an event can be intercepted. When an Event is raised, it can travel from the inside of your DOM to the Outside. This is bubbling. It "bubbles up" the DOM. Events can also travel from the Outside, to the Inside. When doing so, they can be "captured". A Callback is just a function that *responds* to an event.

Comment: Capturing and Bubbling kinda make sense but they still confuse me. What does it mean to travel from the inside of the DOM to the outside?... Does it travel to the 'window' or 'document' object? I am still in the midst of learning about the DOM. The callback makes complete sense. I tried that demo and seen how it was alerted with and without naming the event parameter. I see, without the browser passing event object to the callback you couldn't manipulate events.

Comment: @W3Geek Capturing can differ slightly between browsers. For instance, some browsers won't register the event as far up as the `window`. Capturing means the event starts at `<html>` and then goes to `<body>` and then through each element until it arrives at the element that triggered it. Bubbling is when the event starts at the triggering element, and goes the other direction, ending at the top (`<html>`, the `document`, or `window`). Illustration: http://e-university.wisdomjobs.com/userfiles/image/JavaScript/Figure-9_6.gif

Comment: So to make sure I understand this; basically the handler to an event is the callback? Without a parameter on the callback you can't reference the event object which was automatically passed by the browser itself? I was looking at the try / catch statement and I noticed the catch had an err parameter. This got me to thinking without the browser passing the error event to catch function it couldn't access the error name or message. I don't know if this is the right way to think about it. Also, why do events capture and bubble? Is this just a fancy name for passing the event object?

Comment: @W3Geek *Handlers* and *Callbacks* are similar, but not the same. Callbacks are typically ran after an event has taken place. For instance, your handler (which responds to click events), may invoke your callback. You can reference the event object even without a parameter provided by using the `arguments` array. The event object is always present, even when you don't declare a name for it. It's always available via `arguments[0]`. Capture/Bubble came as a result of different implementations in different browsers earlier on in history.

Comment: I have been trying to read into this more. Is the try / catch statement similar since the error object is passed automatically by the browser?... I know you can explicitly throw the error. What other objects are automatically passed in by the browser?

Comment: @W3Geek Comments aren't for extended discussion. If you have further questions that haven't been answered in your research, please feel free to ask them here on StackOverflow, so long as they are programming related and have definite answers :)

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing the `event` parameter anywhere.  You are just making a function that takes one parameter, called `event`.

When the browser calls the event handlers, it calls the function(s) assigned to it, and passes the `event` object to it as the 1st parameter.

P.S. You don't need the `()` around your function.

```
document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = function (event) {
    alert("The event is: " + "on" + event.type);
};
```

Comment: lol About the () know =D I was just trying it out to see how many different ways you can write functions in JavaScript. There are tons of ways. So, what is the major purpose of the browser automatically passing the event object?...

Comment: @W3Geek: Purpose? That's how browsers work.  The purpose is so you can get info about the event, such as `event.type`.

Answer (score 4):

**You** aren't passing an event into the function, you are naming the first parameter passed to your function `event`.

The browser is the one that is going to call your function and it passes an event object when it calls your function.  You can choose not to name that parameter `function(){}` but the browser is still going to pass the event object in, you can use it or not use it as you see fit.

Comment: That does make sense. The part I do not get is that when I don't choose to name that parameter the code breaks and doesn't work... Here is what I try: document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = (function () { alert("The event is: " + "on" + event.type); });

Comment: @W3Geek It breaks because you're attempting to reference the `type` property of `event`, yet you've not provided the `event` name.

Comment: Well have a look at your code, you are using `event.type`.. what is event if you don't name your parameter event.  It's nothing.  You could use `arguments[0]` if you really wanted, to get the first argument passed to your function without naming it, but that would be kind of silly.  If you want to use `event` then name your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the Event object passed to a handler contains details about the event. For example, a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/KeyboardEvent) contain info about the key pressed, the corresponding character, and any modifier keys (alt, shift, control, meta) that were held down.

> Does the event handler try to pass in an event before it gets assigned or?

The handler is your function, so it's the receiver of `event`, not the passer.

- The event handler is bound when you assign it to the element's `onclick` property (or by calling [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), the modern, preferred method), which is before the handler is invoked.
- The Event object is passed when the handler is invoked, which is when the event fires.

So, when a user clicks on your `#button_1`, this causes a "click" event to fire on the button, which invokes the button's "click" handler, which is passed a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent).

For more information, read about [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the others answers and comments, your code will not work with IE. For cross-browser capability, you need to test the existence of the first argument:

```
<body>
  <button id="button_1">Click Me!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    document.getElementById('button_1').onclick = (
      function(event) {
        var e = event ? event : window.event;
        alert("The event is: " + "on" + e.type);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: In IE 9, the `event` parameter is passed correctly, not sure about older versions.