# How does javascript event handling handle parameters?

Tags: javascript, events, anonymous-function

I know that you can't pass a parameter to the anonymous function on say, a click event:

```
$(.....).click(function(e,'parameter-that-can\'t-be-passed'){
})
```

But why?
I don't understand how the event object is even passed to the function. How is a limitation imposed on the anonymous function by the event handler? It just seems kind of strange to me.

**Update**

For those of you who may stumble upon this question also wondering where the object comes from, it may be due to a lack of knowledge about function callbacks and I encourage you to see this question:

[Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: You forgot to show us your code which probably contains some mistake.

Comment: With that rep you are supposed to know how to ask and what to include to this kind of questions... Please show your code.

Comment: Ok trolls, this was a question of curiosity not help. I changed the question entirely so you don't feel so insecure about not understanding it. Feel free to undo the downvote as you can now feel safe.:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you have to pass the event object as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218722/why-do-you-have-to-pass-the-event-object-as-a-parameter)

Comment: broken link @TilwinJoy

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty doesn't seem broken to me.

Comment: Nevermind, there was another link that you or someone else must have deleted that's no longer there.

Comment: The "specific details" of  [`click`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=jQuery.fn.click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery allows a couple of functions that allows you to pass additional data to a click event. Heres an example

HTML :

```
<button id="button1">HI</button>
<button id="button2">HI</button>
```

JS :

```
var custom = "Hello world";

$('#button1').on('click', {txt:custom}, function (e) {

    this.innerHTML = e.data.txt; // button 1 text changes to Hello world
});

var customfn = function (txt) {
    // the scope of the txt argument will be
    // available in the returning function 
    return function () {
        this.innerHTML = txt; // button 2 text changes to BYE
    }
}

$('#button2').on('click', {txt:custom}, customfn("BYE"));
```

You should also take a look at [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). I haven't tested the code out but the basic idea is there