# Passing data up in an onClick function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm new to React/ES6 and I'm working on my first components. I have a PuzzleContainer component that contains a Puzzle component which displays images. The container component makes an AJAX call to determine what images to display and then passes that data down to the child component. I want to do something in the container component when one of the images is clicked.

Here is my code, I didn't include the componentWillMount() function in the container component, but cards is just an array of strings.

```
class PuzzleContainer extends React.Component {     

    cardClicked(cardsrc) {
        console.log(cardsrc);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="wrapper site-min-height" id="main-wrapper">
                    <Puzzle cards={this.state.cards} cardClicked={this.cardClicked}></Puzzle>
                </section>  
                <Infobar></Infobar>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }


    class Puzzle extends React.Component {
        render() {
        var cards = this.props.cards;
        var html = cards.map((card) =>
            <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 desc">
                <div className="photo-wrapper">
                    <div className="photo">
                        <img className="img-responsive" src={card} onClick={(card) => this.props.cardClicked(card)}></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div className="row mt gutter">{html}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I click an image, a Proxy(?) Object gets printed to the console. It seems to be some object from React. However, my understanding was that it should just print the card value that gets passed to the function, which is a string.

Why is an object getting logged instead of a string? How do I make it so the container component can receive the identity of the image that gets clicked?

Comment: [The answers in this SO question may explain things for you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10218722/2902660)

Comment: the parameter card will have the event object instead of the card src value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use card as both the parameter for the map function as well as the parameter for the onClick function. As a result, the onClick event object is being passed to this.props.cardClicked rather than the string you desire.

Changing your img tag to

```
<img className="img-responsive" src={card} onClick={() => this.props.cardClicked(card)}></img>
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of an `onClick` handler is the `event` object.

`onClick={(card) => this.props.cardClicked(card)}` When you do this, the event object is assigned the name `card` and you are actually passing the event object to `this.props.cardClicked` instead of the `card` variable that you are looping through in `map`.

Do this instead:

```
<img className="img-responsive" 
  src={card} 
  onClick={this.props.cardClicked.bind(this, card)}
/>
```

Btw, `<img>` is self-closing and you can combine the opening and closing tag into one.